# Dictionary has Enum as Value. How can I extract an int[] array? (since enums are "ints")

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, casting, enums

I have a `Dictionary<int,SomeEnum>` and need to return `int[]` of values stored in `SomeEnum`.  Since an Enum is basically an `int`, this should/could work.

I get a compiler error when I do this

```
int[] someResult = myDictionary.Values.ToArray();
```

**Question**

How can I get a list of `int[]` values from `SomeDict<int,SomeEnum>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int[] result = myDictionary.Values.Select( v => (int)v).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This would also produce the desired outcome:

```
int[] result = myDictionary.Values.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```